# A simple riddle related to addition of odd numbers

Tags: logic, puzzle, contest-math

I'm not sure if this type of question can be asked here, but if it can then here goes:

Is it possible to get to 50 by adding 9 positive odd numbers? The odd numbers can be repeated, but they should all be positive numbers and all 9 numbers should be used.

PS : The inception of this question is a result of a random discussion that I was having during the break hour :)

Comment: Hint: adding an odd number of odd numbers will give ... (is this a real question ?)

Comment: Hmm..let me ponder over that

Comment: This says sum of 9 odd numbers can't be even http://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/word/numbers/Numbers_Word_Problems.faq.question.105127.html   True?

Comment: Yes: consider the last digit in binary if it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A direct approach:

Any given integer is either odd or even. If $n$ is even, then it is equal to $2m$ for some integer $m$; and if $n$ is odd, then it is equal to $2m+1$ for some integer $m$. Thus, adding up nine odd integers looks like
$${(2a+1)+(2b+1)+(2c+1)+(2d+1)+(2e+1)\atop +(2f+1)+(2g+1)+(2h+1)+(2i+1)}$$
(the integers $a,b,\ldots,i$ may or may not be the same).
Grouping things together, this is equal to
$$2(a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+4)+1.$$
Thus, the result is odd.

---

An simpler approach would be to prove these three simple facts:
$$\begin{align*}
\mathsf{odd}+\mathsf{odd}&=\mathsf{even}\\
\mathsf{odd}+\mathsf{even}&=\mathsf{odd}\\
\mathsf{even}+\mathsf{even}&=\mathsf{even}
\end{align*}$$
Thus, starting from
$$\mathsf{odd}+\mathsf{odd}+\mathsf{odd}+\mathsf{odd}+\mathsf{odd}+\mathsf{odd}+\mathsf{odd}+\mathsf{odd}+\mathsf{odd}$$
and grouping into pairs,
$$\mathsf{odd}+(\mathsf{odd}+\mathsf{odd})+(\mathsf{odd}+\mathsf{odd})+(\mathsf{odd}+\mathsf{odd})+(\mathsf{odd}+\mathsf{odd})$$
we use our facts to see that this is
$$\mathsf{odd}+\mathsf{even}+\mathsf{even}+\mathsf{even}+\mathsf{even}.$$
Grouping again,
$$\mathsf{odd}+(\mathsf{even}+\mathsf{even})+(\mathsf{even}+\mathsf{even})$$
becomes
$$\mathsf{odd}+\mathsf{even}+\mathsf{even}$$
becomes
$$\mathsf{odd}+(\mathsf{even}+\mathsf{even})=\mathsf{odd}+\mathsf{even}=
\mathsf{odd}$$

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't think I understood your query.

Comment: Shouldn't that be +9?

Comment: @ZettaSuro: $2\cdot 4+1=9$

Comment: Ah..the simpler approach makes sense. So it means it can't be possible, right?

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't see that 4 in the corner.

Comment: @403Forbidden: That's right. I'll add a bit to the first part, let me know if it helps you understand it.

Comment: Yes, it does. Unfortunately, I don't have enough rep to vote up :(

Comment: Or just $$\mathsf{\underbrace{odd+odd}+odd+odd+odd+odd+odd+odd+odd}\\= \mathsf{\underbrace{even+odd}+odd+odd+odd+odd+odd+odd}\\= \mathsf{\underbrace{odd+odd}+odd+odd+odd+odd+odd}\\= \mathsf{\underbrace{even+odd}+odd+odd+odd+odd}\\= \mathsf{\underbrace{odd+odd}+odd+odd+odd}\\= \mathsf{\underbrace{even+odd}+odd+odd}\\= \mathsf{\underbrace{odd+odd}+odd}\\= \mathsf{\underbrace{even+odd}}\\= \mathsf{odd}$$

Comment: @Rahul: Very clever user of MathJax! I approve :)

Comment: @403Forbidden you can always select it (the checkbox under the voting arrows) if you found it most helpful.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{9}(2n_k+1)= 2\sum_{k=1}^9n_k+9$$

$$41=2\sum_{k=1}^9n_k$$

There is no integer $\sum_{k=1}^9n_k$ that satisfies this.

Comment: But my colleague says otherwise. And he refuses to let me in on the solution until the end of day..which is what is killing me. Argh! These math riddles are so addictive

Comment: @403Forbidden he would have to demonstrate that it is possible for the sum of a set of integers to be a non-integer, and if he could do that he's worthy of an award.

Comment: As it turns out, it was just a trick question. He admitted to this (getting a result of 50) being not possible :)